# Power Automate Power BI query retrieve rows that have multiple occurrences within past year

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I'm trying to automate sending an email, that uses data queried from a power bi report.

The outcome of the query I want is

1. where address or plant no is repeated 2 or more times
2. raised date is within the last 365 days

I'm getting issues however, where it keeps returning rows that don't occur multiple times within the last year but may occur multiple times outside of the year.

I then want to compare this against "yesterdays" query, to find the differences and then the email will contain the differences.

Working on the query, I've got

```
EVALUATE
CALCULATETABLE(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        'TableX',
        "Raised Date", 'TableX'[Date Column],
        "Address", 'TableX'[Address Column],
        "Plant No", 'TableX'[Plant Column],
        "Work Order", 'TableX'[Order Column]
    ),
    FILTER(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            'TableX',
            FILTER(
                'TableX',
                'TableX'[Date Column] > NOW() - 365 && 'TableX'[Date Column] <= NOW()
            )
        ),
        VAR DuplicateCount =
            COUNTROWS(
                FILTER(
                    'TableX',
                    'TableX'[Date Column] > NOW() - 365 &&
                    'TableX'[Date Column] <= NOW() &&
                    'TableX'[Address Column] = EARLIER('TableX'[Address Column]) ||
                    'TableX'[Plant Column] = EARLIER('TableX'[Plant Column])
                )
            )
        RETURN
            DuplicateCount >= 2
    )
)
```

I will expand this to 3x in the past 2 years but figured if I can get some help on the 2x 1 year I could replicate it.

Original Dummy data

```
| Order ID | Order Date | Location Address | Plant Number |
|----------|------------|------------------|--------------|
| 1        | 2022-07-15 | Address A        | Plant 123    |
| 2        | 2022-08-10 | Address B        | Plant 234    |
| 3        | 2022-09-05 | Address A        | Plant 345    |
| 4        | 2022-09-12 | Address C        | Plant 456    |
| 5        | 2022-10-20 | Address B        | Plant 123    |
| 6        | 2022-11-30 | Address D        | Plant 234    |
| 7        | 2022-12-15 | Address E        | Plant 345    |
| 8        | 2023-01-05 | Address A        | Plant 123    |
| 9        | 2023-01-20 | Address B        | Plant 234    |
| 10       | 2023-02-10 | Address F        | Plant 567    |
```

Expected output of current query

```
| Order ID | Order Date | Location Address | Plant Number |
|----------|------------|------------------|--------------|
| 1        | 2022-07-15 | Address A        | Plant 123    |
| 2        | 2022-08-10 | Address B        | Plant 234    |
| 3        | 2022-09-05 | Address A        | Plant 345    |
| 5        | 2022-10-20 | Address B        | Plant 123    |
| 8        | 2023-01-05 | Address A        | Plant 123    |
| 9        | 2023-01-20 | Address B        | Plant 234    |
```